# why maven pmd plugin generate pmd.html

Tags: maven, pmd

I have configured my `pom` file for generating `pmd` report using pluging in my pom file.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pmd</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <format>xml</format>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here i am able to create report `pmd.xml` under my project target folder by using:

```
mvn clean compile" command
```

But its creating "site" folder too under that target folder and `pmd.html` file also created inside the site folder.

why.How to configue so that site folder don't get create.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look there to how to remove reports using this plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/removeReport.html

The *target/site* is created because if you check the pmd:check [goal documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html), it says:

> Invokes the execution of this plugin's goal pmd prior to executing itself.

Then checking pmd:pmd [goal documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html), you see about the output directory:

> **The output directory for the final HTML report**. Note that this parameter is only evaluated if the goal is run directly from the command line or during the default lifecycle. If the goal is run indirectly as part of a site generation, the output directory configured in the Maven Site Plugin is used instead.
>   User property is: **project.reporting.outputDirectory.**

And `${project.reporting.outputDirectory}` is by defeault **target/site**

**Edit:** You cannot not generate the HTML project as far as I am aware, however you can change the directory in which the html report is created, using `<outputDirectory>` in the configuration section, for instance:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>pmd</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myHtmlPmdDirectory</outputDirectory>
            <format>xml</format>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
 <plugin>
```

Comment: I dont want to generate site folder.I just need the pmd xml file.

Comment: See my edit regarding modifying your pom to avoid having the HTML report in the site folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I used your plugin configuration But still it is creating pmd.html file under myHtmlPmdDirectory and pmd.xml out side of myHtmlPmdDirectory folder. So I have edited like  this <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
            <format>xml</format>
        </configuration>                                                                                 Now both pmd.html and pmd.xml is getting created undrer target folder of project.Actually i want only pmd.xml not pmd.html.

Comment: Then use /dev/null for the output directory or its Windows equivalent